# How to access activity View components inside fragment in android

Tags: android, page-fragments

I had an edit text in my activity and i want to check that edit text whether it was empty or not from a fragment. Can any one tell me how to access edit text view component present in activity from a fragment in android . I had done this but it is not working .
This is my activity:

```
   package com.developer.mainandroid;


import android.widget.EditText;
import com.milan.tabs.pagerslidingstrip.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.milan.validation.lib.RegExpressionValueValidator;
import com.milan.validation.lib.ValidationManager;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Manual extends FragmentActivity  {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs_sliding_strip;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private Tests adapter_tests;
    TextView welcome_headder;
    String welcome_headder_string;
    public EditText search_edit_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manual);

        ActionBar actionbar;
        actionbar = getActionBar();
        ColorDrawable color_action_bar = new ColorDrawable();
        color_action_bar.setColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
        actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(color_action_bar);  
        search_edit_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_number);
        search_edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        search_edit_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        search_edit_text.setCursorVisible(false);
        search_edit_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                search_edit_text.setCursorVisible(true);

            }
        });

        tabs_sliding_strip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.pager_sliding_tab_strip);
        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter_tests = new Tests(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter_tests);
        final int page_margin = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        pager.setPageMargin(page_margin);
        tabs_sliding_strip.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        tabs_sliding_strip.setTabActiveTextColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        tabs_sliding_strip.setViewPager(pager);
       // tabs_sliding_strip.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));


    }



    public class Tests extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        private final String[] tests_types = {"BEFORE CONNECTING FUSE","AFTER CONNECTING FUSE","PISTON","FINAL AMMUNITATION"};

        public Tests(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tests_types[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return tests_types.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ManualMode_BC_Fuse_ckt();
            case 1:
                return new Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt();
            case 2:
                return new piston();
            case 3:
                return new Manualmode_final();
            }
            return new ManualMode_BC_Fuse_ckt();
        }

    }
```

}

This is my fragment activity:

package com.developer.mainandroid;

```
import com.milan.material.widget.FloatingEditText;
import com.milan.validation.lib.RegExpressionValueValidator;
import com.milan.validation.lib.ValidationManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt extends Fragment {

    Manual manual_child;
    static FloatingEditText number_edit_text;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manualmode_ac_fuse_ckt, null);
         manual_child = new Manual();
        number_edit_text = (FloatingEditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edt_number);

        registerForContextMenu(table_fuse_afer_cnc);
        return Root_view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("MANUAL MODE : AFTER FUSE CONNECTION");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "TEST  ");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "SELECT ALL  ");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "DESELECT ALL  ");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle()=="TEST  ")
        {
            if(manual_child.search_edit_text.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else{

            //Do some operations

            }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="SELECT ALL  ")
        {

        }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="DESELECT ALL  ")
        {

        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(activity.getClass()==Manual.class){
            manual_child = (Manual)activity;
        }
    }
    }
```

This is my Logcat:

```
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at com.developer.mainandroid.Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt.onCreateView(Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt.java:74)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 03:07:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(13424):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Don't get it actually what  you're asking about?

Comment: Sorry for late reply I want to access edit text from fragment which was present in main activity dude @MD

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
EditText  editText =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.EditText);
```

Answer (score 2):

After a Long discussion with my friend in stack over flow I had found the solution to access view components present inside parent activity from Fragment

Make  the view component as **public static** in your parent activity and make sure that fragment activity of same package

This is the my code:
Parent Activity:

```
public class Sample extends FragmentActivity  {
 public static EditText meditText;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout....);
{
meditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_1);

}
}
```

In Fragment Activity:

```
public class Example extends Fragment {

Sample sample_child;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.....);
sample_child = new Sample();
if(sample_child.meditText.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enter text or number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
return Root_view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For short you can do this.
In your framgment, in onResume(). Call
`((YourActivityClass)getActivity()).edit_text`.

For long, you must know that `getActivity()` is not always return your activity, some time it will return null. So you must do 2 step.

1. Get the activity in onAttach() then cast it to your activity and save it in your fragment

`public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(activity.getClass()== YourActivity.class){
            mActivity = (YourActivity) activity;
        }
    }`

2. Access your edit_text through your activity variable like this

`mActivity.edit_text`

**UPDATE #1:**
I will change your oncreateview of your fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manualmode_ac_fuse_ckt, null);




    manual_child = new Manual();
    number_edit_text = (FloatingEditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edt_number);

    registerForContextMenu(table_fuse_afer_cnc);
    return Root_view;


}
```

into this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manualmode_ac_fuse_ckt, null);

    number_edit_text = (FloatingEditText)manual_child.findViewById(R.id.edt_number);

    registerForContextMenu(table_fuse_afer_cnc);
    return Root_view;

}
```

**UPDATE #2:**
change

```
if(manual_child.search_edit_text.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

into this

```
if(manual_child.search_edit_text.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(manual_child, "Please enter number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Comment: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare edittext object as static then in fragment you can use like

```
Mainactivity.edittextobj.setText("Test");
```

Comment: you dont need this to be in fragment  Manual manual=new Manual(); just use Maunal.edittext object

Answer (score 0):

Use Validation For That Like This:-
In Main Class:-

```
  if (!(Validation.validateUsername(nameString))) {
                    editxt_name.setError(Html
                            .fromHtml("<font color='red'>Please enter username</font>"));
                    return;
```

And in Validation Class:

```
public static boolean validateUsername(String username) {
    if (username.length() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could override method in class Manual:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

and invoke if sentence in it

update---> write this method in Activity class Manual:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getTitle()=="TEST  ")
    {
        if(manual_child.search_edit_text.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else{

        //Do some operations

        }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="SELECT ALL  ")
    {

    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="DESELECT ALL  ")
    {

    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I didn't get u dude @Eric

Comment: i need to call from fragment dude @Eric